# How do I use the Searchmask for FORFILES in batch?

Tags: batch-file

So I am trying to use `forfiles /M DX* /P ..\fsb /C "cmd /c cd ..\extracted && fsb2wav @path"` to extract .wav files from .fsb files.
But I need to extract only the files that are formatted like DX*.fsb and no DX*_FR.fsb or DX*_DE.fsb where * any be any number of alphanumeric characters.
Is there a way to do that? I have been messing around with the /M option but it does not seem to like regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wildcard `*` stands for any number of characters valid in file/path names (`?` stands for a single valid character), so you need to do the filtering yourself.

For your task at hand I would not use `forfiles` here, because it is quite slow as it instances a new `cmd` instance for every iteration and it is more complicated to apply an additional filter. The way I would go for is a `for /F` loop that parses the output of a `dir /B` command piped into `findstr`:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Define constants here:
set "WORKDIR=..\extracted"
set "SEEKDIR=..\fsb"
set "DIRFILT=DX*.fsb"
set "REGEXPR=^DX[0-9A-Z]*.fsb$"

pushd "%SEEKDIR%" && (
    for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('
        dir /B "%DIRFILT%" ^| ^
            findstr /I /R "%REGEXPR%"
    ') do (
        pushd "%WORKDIR%" && (
            ECHO fsb2wav "%%~fF"
            popd
        )
    )
    popd
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

After having tested the script, remove the upper-case `ECHO` to actually execute the `fsb2wav` tool.

Comment: When I put the script in a .bat file and run it it does nothing. This is my first time messing around with batch, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do not double-click the batch file but run it from a command prompt window; you will see that it outputs the `fsb2wav` command lines instead of executing them for testing purposes; regard the last sentence in my answer; note that the batch script must be in the correct location, bacause you are using relative paths (I just copied them from your question); so as far as I got it, there must be three directories at the same location: `fsb` (containing the source files), `extracted` (to store the converted files) and another one where the script is placed...

Comment: Ok, I am starting to understand what you did, it was just the REGEXPR that was messed up. What purpose does the DIRFILT serve?

Comment: `DIRFILT` is not mandatory, but in case of many files in the directory, it reduces the number of items passed over to `findstr` and could therefore lead to slightly improved performance...

Comment: Yeah, there are about 75,000 files in the directory, it could be useful. No matter how I tried to put the output in a different directory, I could not do it, so now I am just trying to pipe the output of the fsb2wav in a move command to send it to another directory, is that a good solution? Also, how do I make sure the pipe sends its output to the source_directory parameter and not the target_directory parameter?

Comment: You cannot pipe into a move command; a pipe redirects the console output of a command into the console input of another one, for instance `type "\path\tofile.txt" | find "search_text"`; I do not know the `fsb2wav` tool, but perhaps it supports a second argument for the (full path to the) target file, so you could try `fsb2wav "%%~fF" ".\%%~nF.wav"`; if not, you need to place `move "%%~dpnF.wav" ".\%%~nF.wav"` after the `fsb2wav` command line (supposing the output `.wav` file has got the same name as the input `.fsb` file)...

Comment: I managed to work around by putting the pushd and popd around the fsb2wav

Comment: Alright, I implemented that in my answer now, because I realised that the script might not behave as expected when relative directory paths are given...

Comment: Yeah that seems to work, if a tad bit slower. My fsb2wav tool is a program made three years ago by a modder since retired for a moderately successful game: its only purpose is to make that conversion. \n d

Comment: Do you know how to use the findstr pattern parameter? I am looking to match strings that do not end a certain way but the standard regex won't work.

Comment: Type `findstr /?` in a command prompt window for more help; as you can see, there is only a small collection of expressions supported, so it has actually got nothing to do with real regular expressions...

Comment: Ok, I managed to do it by piping the output of the DIR into successive inverted FINDSTR. so inside the selector  of the for loop I have ` dir /B "%DIRFILT%" ^| findstr /V /I /R "DX.*_es_ES.fsb" ^| findstr /V /I /R "DX.*_it_IT.fsb" ^| findstr /V /I /R "DX.*_fr_FR.fsb" ^| findstr /V /I /R "DX.*_de_DE.fsb" `  EDIT: It won't parse properly

Comment: You could specify multiple reg.expr.s like this: `findstr [/V] [/I] /R /C:"regex1" /C:"reges2" ...`; since you want to match the entire file names, you could specify the `/X` switch...